# Format number without decimal in php

Tags: php

I need to print number like this: 123 456 789. (separate it with space). I use a `number_format`, but I don´t know how to delete decimals.

```
number_format(123456789, 2, ',', ' ')
//output is 123 456 789,00
```

When I use this:

```
number_format(123456789)
//output is 123,456,789 - it is not correct
```

UPDATE: I was wrong. Something has happened that it was not worked. But this is right solution. Thanks for help.

```
number_format(123456789, 0, '', ' ') <--- this is correct
```

Comment: `number_format(xxx);`? If you would have read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) you would have known.

Comment: No, because then output is 123,456,789

Comment: You know the manual is there for a reason!

Comment: What did you think the second parameter does?

Comment: Maybe number_format can't do this. Is there any other function how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass zero to the second parameter, which is the number of decimal places:

```
number_format(123456789, 0, '', ' ')
```

Comment: Or just leave the 3 last parameters out since it has default `0` decimals.

Comment: @putvande No, because OP wants the thousands separator to be a space.

Comment: The OP wants spaces rather than commas, so this is spot on.

Comment: Is there any other function how can I do this?